# Primefaces fileUpload change POST URI

Tags: post, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 6 fileUpload component along with a URL rewrite framework.
So that, http requests to: domain/URI/fileupload are routed to: domain/OTHER_URI/upload.xhtml

I submit this with a different commandButton as javascript `PF('fileUploadWidget').submit();`

When the file is POSTed to the server, it's using the wrong path (OTHER_URI/upload.xhtml) and failing.

I've tried locating and changing this in the javascript widgetvar object as well as the form on the page, but it still POSTs to the wrong URI. How can I change the URL where PrimeFaces fileupload submits?

Thank you

Comment: I may have that version in the project, I will try. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using OmniFaces version 1.14 and using useRequestURI="true". It now POSTs to domain/appContext, instead of domain/appContext/URI/fileupload, I first hit the page at domain/appContext/URI/fileupload. I'm working on updating OmniFaces to hopefully achieve different results.Thank you for your help!

Comment: I use ocpsoft rewrite. I found an error in my configuration and explained in my posted answer. Thank you for taking the time to respond to this question. You are a hero to this community. Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing the URL rewrite configuration.

I was mapping /fileUpload to a path in WEB-INF. This caused POSTs to an unreachable location. Instead of trying to change the POST URL, I mapped to an accessible path, outside of WEB-INF.